# Handling data trees in python with changing node attributes

Tags: python, tree, nodes

I have a tree where I want to dynamically add or remove nodes. For now I just want to focus on adding nodes. I want to create python class in such a way that adding one node will recalculate attributes (x and y axis coordinates) of affected nodes. I have attached below diagrams to better explain the behaviour that I want to handle via python script.
[steps for building tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aok5D.jpg)

I am looking to create Node class, but not sure how I create and handle x values using methods. Anyone can shed some light? Any links to blogs?

Comment: The information necessary to answer your question must be in the question itself, as text, not some external site.

Comment: Coding and special reqs aside `graphviz` can draw trees.  Networkx too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are libraries doing this. If you want to implement it yourself, following approach may help:

1. Find the height of the tree. Use it to find the bottom line's y value.
2. Evenly distribute all leaf nodes at y. Group them by their parents. If needed, put some more gap between nodes with different parents.
3. Going one level up, place the parent of a group above the middle node(s). Calculating y should be trivial.
4. Repeat 3 until all nodes are placed.

Comment: Thank you for response burkay. However problem for me is calculating x value and not y. I need to keep changing x so that newly added nodes wont overlap. At the same time handle parent node x axis value to ensure they are somewhere in the middle of its own child nodes.
for y rule is simple child y axis value = parent y + 1

Comment: Ok, above approach would solve this case. Key point is starting with the bottom line of leaf nodes instead of the top line of root node.